# ActiveMQ: sometimes stops sending messages from one broker to another broker

Tags: activemq-classic

I have 2 brokers with duplex bridge configuration.
Sometimes there is the following situation: there is a connection between the brokers, the message from broker B to broker A forwarded normally. But from the broker A to the broker B not forwarded. When you restart the broker B all messages are sent.  In the logs there are no errors.
ActiveMQ version 5.10.

Configuration of broker A:

```
<transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector
                name="clientConnection"
                uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61617?needClientAuth=true%26trace=true"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

Configuration of broker B:

```
 <networkConnectors>
             <networkConnector uri="static:(failover:(ssl://${host}:${port}))"
                               name="B"
                               userName="${jms.login}"
                               password="${jms.password}"
                               duplex="true"
                               conduitSubscriptions="true">
                 <excludedDestinations>
                     <queue physicalName="test.Orders"/>
                     <queue physicalName="test.Results"/>
                 </excludedDestinations>
             </networkConnector>           
 </networkConnectors>
```

How to make a reliable duplex bridge?

Answer (score 1):

For better or worse, this is default behavior.  The idea is to avoid messages bouncing all over when there are consumers on multiple brokers in the cluster.  Messages will not be replayed to a broker they have already been on, or have met their "time to live" (or max number of broker hops).

You can get a detailed explanation on what you can do here at the bottom of the page: ([Netorks of Brokers: Stuck Messages](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html)

I'm not entirely convinced that all the bugs have been worked out of replayWhenNoConsumers, so if you go that route, be aware that things may still be off.